# Extract string from XML using Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have an xml node that i want to check for a specific string for example `<name.firstname>john</name.firstname>` therefore i want to run through the whole xml file and find all firstname and then get the value which is john can anyone help me with this

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you check xml primer in groovy: http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the XML was formatted like this:

```
<results>
 <person>
  <name.firstname>john</name.firstname>
 </person>
 <person>
  <name.firstname>mary</name.firstname>
 </person>
</results>
```

With Groovy and [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) you can parse out the first name element with following code:

```
def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text) 
def people = results.person // list of person elements of type NodeChildren
people.each{ person ->
 String name = person."name.firstname".text()
 println name
}
```

You need to quote the "name.firstname" element since the "." would be confused with the XPath notation.

Comment: Actually I did that but for what im currently doing that is not efficient I am using DOMcategory for parsing the trick is to search firstname and overlook the rest